# YouTube error with XBMC Kodi

Tags: kodi, youtube

I have successfully installed YouTube from the official Kodi repository. However when I try to play a video I get an error.

```
Exception in contentprovider unknown kind
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: To be honest I can't remember, I'll look it up and edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed advice from this [page](http://www.johnlarge.co.uk/2016/02/23/kodi-youtube-plugin-broken-fix/) and logged into the YouTube application on Kodi twice and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.